# Run script after all interfaces were up in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, boot, routing, network-interface

In order to setup a load-balanced permanent routes in debian, according to [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/377) article, i have to run the following command

```
ip route add default scope global \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth0 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth1 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth2 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth3 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth4 weight 1 \
    nexthop via 10.100.0.254 dev eth5 weight 1
```

after all interfaces were up. I think the best place to put that command is if-up.d folder, but scripts there are running onec for each interface, and i can't get how to run this command only once after last interface was up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run it once after all interfaces are setup with:

`post-up ip route add....` as the last line of `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Comment: according to `man interfaces` it wouldn't mean "after all", it will be just "post-up" of last interface in a file, but what if for some reason interfaces will be initialized in different order?

Comment: true but if you put the line as last line of the file (or after defining all the interfaces), I understand this as meaning after the last interface of all the above that come up and not only the last defined. This is my understanding but tbh I never thought it could be different so I never considered the subject. Anyways I never had problem using it this way (loading iptables rules for example).